# difficulty with optional groups

Tags: regex

Regex was always a dark art for me and I've been out of programming for too long, but this is either not possible/as straightforward as I hope.

I'm trying to write to regex to search the following text

```
 8825| -  MIA *** LHR **  JFK JFK -  DME -  SIN *** *** SYD *** SIN *** LHR **   -   -  BOS *** LHR  -   -   -  GRU *** ***
```

it should match

```
MIA *** LHR ** or
JFK JFK or 
SIN *** *** SYD *** SIN *** LHR ** or
BOS *** LHR or
GRU *** *** or
DME
```

This

```
([A-Z]{3})\s(([A-Z]{3}|[*]{2,3})\s)+
```

matches everything part from

```
DME
```

and now I'm stuck. Any help or pointers gratefully received.

Comment: I really don't understand... What do your should-match patterns have in common????

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :** (**If** I did guess what you might need...) - **UPDATED**

```
([A-Z]{3}\s([A-Z]{3}|([\*]{2,3}\s){1,2})?)+
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30po5

**Matches :**

```
MIA *** LHR **
JFK JFK
SIN *** *** SYD *** SIN *** LHR **
BOS *** LHR
GRU *** ***
DME
```

Comment: Subject to more data testing I think I found my fix  `([A-Z]    {3})\s(([A-Z]{3}|[*]{2,3})\s)*`  Needed to change the + for * at the end

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the example given:

```
[A-Z]{3}(((?:\s*[*]{3}\s*)+([A-Z]{3})+)*(\s*[*]{2,3}\s*?)?)|[A-Z]{3}(\s*[A-Z]{3})?
```

However, I would suggest that you specify more strict rules as to what you want to match - without doing this all we are doing here is just guessing and the regex that we come up with might not work for other examples if they are in any way different.